# how to create similar php pages but with different urls

Tags: php

I'm currently learning php so I'm a beginner I have learned the basics and some advanced stuff but now I'm trying to make a project to help me learn faster which will be basically a Math test in times table in which a user will enter the site, and then the user will enter his name and click 'Begin test' to enter the test which is 10 questions. the user need to answer the question first by clicking on a button and then click on 'Next' to go to next question and after finishing 10 questions the result will be shown to him something like "You have answered `CorrectAnswersNumber` from total of 10 questions!".

I have made something like this when I was learning ASP.Net MVC but in php it is a bit complicated. So my question is should I need to create 10 php pages that contains code to generate random numbers for the questions? if so how can I pass whether the user has answered the question right or wrong?

What I have did so far is the page in the first which contain the username and save it by using a session here is my code for the index.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Math Test</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #DDD">
<h1 style="font-size: 75px;" align="center">Math Test</h1>

<form method="POST" action="Math_Test.php">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="text" name="Name" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; font- 
size: 75px; color: blue;">
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Begin Test" style="width: 250px auto; 
height: 100px auto; font-size: 75px;">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code for the secondpage:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $Name = $_POST['Name'];

    } else {
        echo "<h1 align='center' style='margin-top: 250px;'>Sorry, You can't 
 access this page directly.<br /> Please go back ant try again or simply 
 click <a 
href=\"index.php\"> here!</a></h1>";
    }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Math Test</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #DDD;">
    <?php echo "<h1 align='center' style='font-size: 100px;'>Hi " . $Name . 
"</h1>"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don’t need separate pages. You can keep track of what’s going on in a session and show the questions etc based on that

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I wonder if you can explain what did you say like how can I do it with the session

Comment: This is a great, simple but devious problem, that will teach you the ins and outs of form processing and likely draw you into state management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this on your index page

```
<?php

// starts session
session_start();

    // check if submit button was clicked
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
        // check if name was provided
        if ( $name !== '' ) {
            // store name in session
            $_SESSION = array(
                'answered_questions' => 0,
                'correct_answers' => 0,
                'wrong_answers' => 0,
                'name' => $name
            );
            // redirect to second page
            header('Location: second_page.php');
            exit();
        }

        // set error if name was not provided
        $error = 'Please provide your name';
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Math Test</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #DDD">
<h1 style="font-size: 75px;" align="center">Math Test</h1>

<?php
    // no name was provided so display the error message
    if ( isset($error) ) {
        echo '<p style="color: red">'. $error . '</p>'
    }
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="text" name="name" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; font- 
size: 75px; color: blue;">
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Begin Test" style="width: 250px auto; 
height: 100px auto; font-size: 75px;">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then on your second page you do something like so

```
<?php
// starts session
session_start();

    // check if name key and value is not in the session
    // if not there, then redirect back to the index.php page
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['name']) ) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        $answer = (int)$_POST['answer'];
        $expected_answer = $_SESSION['first'] * $_SESSION['second'];

        $_SESSION['answered_questions'] += 1;

        if ( $expected_answer == $answer ) {
            $_SESSION['correct_answers'] += 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['wrong_answers'] += 1;
        }

        if ( $_SESSION['answered_questions'] == 10 ) {
            // reset the session values from that page except name of course
            header('Location: show_results.php');
            exit();
        }

        $_SESSION['first'] = rand(1, 10); // random number between 1 and 20
        $_SESSION['second'] = rand(1, 10);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['first'] = rand(1, 10); // random number between 1 and 20
        $_SESSION['second'] = rand(1, 10);
    }
    // set the variable name to value in the session
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Math Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?>
    <h1>Hello, <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <p><?php 
            echo $_SESSION['first'] . ' * ' . $_SESSION['second'] . ' = ';
        ?><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" required></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then after if you want you can handle all the logic on the second page if you want as per @SamiKuhmonen advice

Comment: Can you explain to me those if conditions because I didn't understand them. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @MohammadSherif i have added some comments in the code to help explain those if conditions. If you still need help, please let me know

Comment: thanj you for the help now I understand but I did it with a different method which I wrote `required` in the input tag and did pretty well. now my problem is I don't know how can I actually get questions one by one until I finish and then print the result .. I made a function `questionGenerator` which will generate two random numbers and set the correct answer to `rnd1 * rnd2` and then generate random wrong answers but I don't know what to do next?

Comment: @MohammadSherif i have edited my answer to help you with that, now if may be so bold as to recommend the best resource to learn php from top to bottom it would be this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-PHP-5-3-Matt-Doyle/dp/0470413964)

Comment: I'm marking your answer as the most helpful but now I have a problem can you please check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033315/how-to-fix-an-array-of-inputs-and-display-it-correctly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do 10 pages for PHP to handle the math test that you are trying to do, instead, there is a technique called AJAX, which you can read about it from this URL: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm
they have a very nice tutorial that deals with databases as well, which will help you in your case.

Give it a look and try to implement it, it will help you learn much faster.

Just for the record, PHP does have MVC frameworks, two are popular for developers,

Laravel: https://laravel.com/

Codeigniter: https://codeigniter.com/

Both supports MVC, I'll recommend you to go first with Codeigniter, once you feel that you are comfortable in PHP, switch to Laravel.

All the best, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks you for the ajax part I will read it. but when I was working with MVC I didn't like it I only mention that part because it was the way I handled the problem with. and I wan't to make it without any framework because it's for training purposes only. again thank you very much for the help