# How to fix an array of inputs and display it correctly

Tags: php, forms, post

This Question is a bit long and I have edited too much to reduce my code but I hope anyone can help me out please!

I'm working on a Math test in times table project with php which will ask the user to enter his name and then ask him 10 questions like "2 x 2 = ?" giving four buttons to choose an answer and then after answering 10 questions the user will be redirected to `result.php` page which will show the result and here is what I wrote so far in `homePage.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

    $_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['CorrectAnswers'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['QuestionsAsnwered'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['QuestionsAnswered'] = 0;

    header("location: MathTest.php");

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Math Test</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Begin Test"">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in MathTest.php which contains the problem:

```
<?php

session_start();
//just controlling user answer no problem here
if (isset($_POST[$_SESSION['UserAnswer']])) {
    if ($_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] == 10) {
        header("location: result.php");
    }

    if ($_SESSION['UserAnswer'] == $_SESSION['CorrectAnswer']) {
        $_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['CorrectAnswers'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['QuestionsAnswered'] += 1;
        QuestionGenerator();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['QuestionsAnswered'] += 1;
        QuestionGenerator();
    }
}
//I think that my problem(written down) is here
function QuestionGenerator(){
    $rnd1 = rand(1, 12);
    $rnd2 = rand(2, 12);

    $CorrectAnswer = $rnd1 * $rnd2;
    $WrongAnswer1 = $CorrectAnswer - 2;
    $WrongAnswer2 = $CorrectAnswer + 2;
    $WrongAnswer3 = $CorrectAnswer + 4;

    $_SESSION['rnd1'] = $rnd1;
    $_SESSION['rnd2'] = $rnd2;

    $_SESSION['CorrectAnswer'] = $CorrectAnswer;
    $_SESSION['WrongAnswer1'] = $WrongAnswer1;
    $_SESSION['WrongAnswer2'] = $WrongAnswer2;
    $_SESSION['WrongAnswer3'] = $WrongAnswer3;

    $_SESSION['AnswersArray'] = array($_SESSION['CorrectAnswer'], $_SESSION['WrongAnswer1'], $_SESSION['WrongAnswer2'], $_SESSION['WrongAnswer3']);
}

function EchoAnswers($array) {
    shuffle($array);    
    echo "<form method='POST' action='' ";
    foreach ($array as $_SESSION['UserAnswer']) {
        echo "<button><input style='width: 200px; height: 100px; font-size: 75px;' type='submit' name='" . $_SESSION['UserAnswer'] . "' value='" . $_SESSION['UserAnswer'] . "' ></button";
    }
    echo "</form>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php echo "<h1 align='center' style='font-size: 75px;'>Question " . $_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] . " of 10</h1>"; ?>

    <h2 align="center" style="font-size: 60px"><?php echo $_SESSION['rnd1'] . " X " .  $_SESSION['rnd2'] . " = ?" ?></h2>
    <div align="center">
        <?php EchoAnswers($_SESSION['AnswersArray']) ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when I click on any button it will only shuffle the answers but if I press the last button it will work full functionally

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Comment: @JohnConde I have edited my question and reduced the amount of code is it now better or should I reduce it more?

Comment: Might I suggest a refactor?  Firstly, I would do all of this client-side in JavaScript, since no server-side resource is actually needed for this.  But, I understand this project might just be a PHP experiment for something else later on.  In that case, consider posting the problem as well as the suggested answer.  No need to track all of this in session data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that there is 4 submit buttons each with different `name` tag so the session will only store the last input button and will make it functional but for the others it will only refresh the page with no different because they are not being controlled by php code so to solve this problem I only changed the EchoAnswers function like this:

```
function EchoAnswers($array) {
    shuffle($array);    
    echo "<form method='POST' action='' ";
    foreach ($array as $_SESSION['UserAnswer']) {
        echo "<button><input style='margin: 10px; border: 3px solid black; background-color: lightblue; width: 200px; height: 100px; font-size: 75px;' type='submit' name='UserAnswer' value='" . $_SESSION['UserAnswer'] . "' ></button";
    }
    echo "</form>";
}
```

the `name` tag was also set to `$_SESSION['UserAnswer']` so I changed this part to a normal name and I also changed the php code like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['UserAnswer'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] == 10) {
        header("location: result.php");
    }

    if ($_SESSION['UserAnswer'] == $_SESSION['CorrectAnswer']) {
        $_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['CorrectAnswers'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['QuestionsAnswered'] += 1;
        QuestionGenerator();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['QuestionNumber'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['QuestionsAnswered'] += 1;
        QuestionGenerator();
    }
}
```

the part that I have changed in php code is `isset($_POST['UserAnswer'])` because `UserAnswer` was set to `$_SESSION['UserAnswer']` instead of normal name in the name tag.

Comment: am glab you figured it out but please look at the book i recommended to you from the previous question